# How conditioning happens?

Tags: regression, causality, conditioning

F. Elwert and C. Winship in the paper "[Endogenous Selection Bias: The Problem of Conditioning on a Collider Variable](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-soc-071913-043455)" (content available [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6089543/)) discuss *conditioning* on different types of variables.

However, they do not discuss deeply *conditioning* itself. They limit describing it to practical definition: "*introducing information about a variable into an analysis, e.g., via sample selection, stratification, regression control*".

I am interested in more ways in which conditioning may happen in regression analysis. **Are these three ways (sample selection, stratification, regression control) exhausting all possibilities how conditioning may happen?** Are there any other options?

Comment: Those are the main ways I know about.

Comment: There are limitless ways in which conditioning can happen.  Literally any situation in which not all variables are observed and something needs to be said about other variables involves conditioning, by definition, and virtually all of those situations can be conceived of as "regression analysis."  In particular, that will include *everything* anyone wishes to say about future events.  As such, if this question is at all suitable here on CV, it should be treated as CW.

Comment: @whuber I dont get it. If you think that something in this question should be changed, please elaborate more.

Comment: I'm not suggesting a change: I'm only remarking that this type of question that seeks a long list of possible examples is not a good fit on any SE site.

Comment: Neither I expect, nor I ask for long list of examples. My question is IF there are other options. Sometimes it is proven, that all problems of some kind can be encompassed somewhere (like proofs for turing machine). Sometimes there are papers, that aim to exhaust a problem. Of course, if you feel, that the question could be specified more precisely, and better fit CV please suggest changes.

Comment: I realize you didn't expect a long list of examples: *but there are.*  That doesn't make for a good question here.

Comment: Could you please at least refer to some?